what types of numbers can be decomposed as sums of concatenations
I wrote a website that decomposes a number into the sum and difference of concatenations - https://andsha.pythonanywhere.com / . Which numbers can be represented only as the sum of concatenations

I think repdigit (репдиджиты or репдигиты) might be a better word than concatenation.  Your algorithm gives $543 = 555 - (11 + (1))$ while it could have given $543 = 444+99$ and you could use both approaches for most numbers.  What are the rules for a representation? Must the repdigit numbers be of different lengths? If so, you will find numbers like $23$ difficult to represent with subtractions

Нenry, the numbers can be of any length, only one condition is that they are repdigit and at the same time the sum gives the original number. 23 = 22 +1. My algorithm, which is implemented on the site, actually decomposes into the sum and difference of repdigit. I ask you to either specify which numbers can be represented only as a sum or specify an algorithm that represents any number as a sum repdigit

It is not totally clear what the rules are for acceptable sums.
Consider $21$.  Can you say $21=11+9+1$?  If so, any positive integer can be written as a sum of repdigits.
But if not (because $9$ and $1$ have the same length) then I think the numbers which can be written as a sum of repdigits of different lengths are those in OEIS A065039 and those which cannot are in OEIS A065438
